# Find closest indices given a list of indices

Tags: algorithm, go

I ran into this while solving a programming question, so seeking help with a subset of the original problem.

The indexes of a, b, and c are provided in a slice of slice of integers ([][]int).

For example:

```
indexes := [][]int{{0, 10}, {3, 9}, {5, 12}}
```

where a is found at indices 0 and 10. 
b is found at indices 3 and 9 
c is found at indices 5 and 12.

The goal is to find, programmatically, which of the indexes for a, b and c makes them closest. For example, in the above case, the answer would be 10, 9, 12.

What would be a way to solve this? I have thought about dynamic programming but still cannot figure out how to represent this problem in a recursive way.
Non Dp solution also welcome, just looking for ideas not entire solution.

I think I am close but still not there (see min() function) - https://play.golang.org/p/odw9u-JeOPU

Comment: Just to comment. Your `min` function peels a single index set off, but doesn't compare it as it needs to. Instead of working with a, b, c, etc separately, you need to find the closest `n` length tuple (3 in this example). So the length of the outer slice determines that portion of the complexity and is what the recursion should be based off... unless my 4AM tired brain isn't firing on all cylinders...

Comment: @RayfenWindspear right. That is the issue. What I think I need is to recursively find min with something like.. 
 min({{0, 10}, {3, 9}, {5, 12}})
  -- min ({0}, {3, 9}, {5, 12})  
   -- min {3}, {5, 12}
        -- min {5} 
               -- min {12}

Comment: I'm not sure there's a solution that doesn't involve comparing every possible tuple. I came to an iterative solution rather than recursive. Basically, I generated all the combinations for (a,b,c), then scored them individually. Perhaps a dynamic solution could involve keeping track of the best score yet and immediately tossing out known sets. e.g. 10,9,12 is best score with 5, if that's seen earlier, the set 0,9,5 could immediately be ruled out as soon as it saw 0,9 making that score at least 9. I'd post my code, but it's a gory mess.

Comment: A combinatorial explosion? See [Travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) and [NP-hardness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness).

Comment: It sounds like a Travelling salesman version, without a specific start/end point. You can add a fake 2nd coordinate to use the same algorithms.